# Meteor: Querying a collection based on a URL parameter

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-autoform, meteor-helper

I am trying display the unique profile of a babysitter (i.e: babysitter username, city, postal code, etc ... ) from a schema/collection called "Babysitters" .

The URL correctly contains the babysitter unique _id, say:

> http://localhost:3000/test/PqMviBpYAmTA2b5ec

but I don't manage to retrieve all the other fields.

[meteor question - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbi2P.jpg)

I have tried querying the MongoDB in two files: routes.js and the template test.js

**1) in routes.js**

```
Router.route('/test/:_id', {
name: 'test',
data: function () {

return Babysitters.findOne({ _id: this.params._id });
}
});
```

**2) in test.js**

```
Template.test.helpers({

 data: function () {

 //sitterusername = this.params.sitterusername;
 //console.log(this.params._id );

 return Babysitters.findOne( { _id: this.params._id });
 }
 });
```

**the html file: test.html**

```
<template name="test"> 
    {{#with data}}
    <ul>
        <li><img src="/" {{photourl}} height="100" width="100" ></li>
        <li>Babysitter username: {{ sitterusername }}</li>
        <li>Presentation: {{ presentation }}</li>
        <li>City: {{ city  }}</li>
        <li>Postal Code: {{ postalcode  }}</li>
        <li>Mother tongue: {{ mothertongue  }}</li>
        <li>Languages spoken {{ languagesspoken }}</li>
        <li>Experience {{ experience }}</li>
        <li>Homework help: {{ homeworkhelpavailable }}</li>
        <li>Hourly wages: {{ hourlywages }} €/h</li>
   </ul>
   {{/with}}
</template>
```

I have tried all sorts of ways but the Collection fields never appear in the HTML file.

Thanks for your help, a newbie here.

K.

Comment: Which router are you using?

Comment: What happens if you write 'console.log(Babysitters.findOne( { _id: this.params._id }));' in the browser console when the app is running?

Comment: 1) Router is Iron Router

Comment: 2) When I run console.log(Babysitters.findOne( { _id: this.params._id })); in the console, I get : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Comment: You'd have to be at a breakpoint in the router for `this.params._id` to be defined. That command won't work from just any state in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are not publishing all `Babysitters` to the client so your `.findOne()` returns nothing.

This is a common router pattern where you want to display a single document which is not normally published. A good way to solve this in i-r is to `waitOn` a subscription to the individual document:

```
waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('oneBabysitter', this.params._id);
}
```

On the server, publish:

```
Meteor.publish('oneBabysitter',function(_id){
  return Babysitters.find(_id);
});
```

Note that even though this publication is only going to return a single document you still have to do a `.find()` and not a `.findOne()` because publications need to return a cursor or array of cursors, not objects.

Comment: I have implemented in  routes.js:  `Router.route('/test/:_id', {
    name: 'test',
    waitOn: function(){
      return Meteor.subscribe('oneBabysitter', this.params._id);
    }
});` and in server\publish.js `Meteor.publish('oneBabysitter',function(_id){
  return Babysitters.find({ _id: this.params._id }));`

Comment: I am not quite there: I am directed to the correct URL for a babysitter, ex: <http://localhost:3000/test/PqMviBpYAmTA2b5ec> but the loading.html  template is displayed instead of the test.html template. Any suggestions ?

Comment: My apologies, I cut and pasted once too many. The publish function doesn't know about `this.params` obviously. Try the updated publish.

Comment: Hello, I had already  `publish('oneBabysitter',function(this.params._id)` Any idea why I am redirected to the loading template and not to the test.html template ?